# I've been trying to fetch the data from a URL by using UrlFetchApp in appscript but in my case it returns empty values, How to solve this problem?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets, urlfetch

Actually,  I'm trying to fetch the data from this **[First URL](https://fbatoolkit.com/estimate_ajax?category=UGV0IFN1cHBsaWVz&rank=6000)** and when I browse it in chrome at the very first time it returns an array having key's with blank values but when I load the **[Index Page](https://fbatoolkit.com/)** of this website and then reload the **first URL** then it returns an array having key's with their values and from this, I'm assuming that the **first URL** depends on cookies and only the **index page** creates the cookies and when I try to get the data from **First URL** by using **UrlFetchApp** method in app-script it returns only keys with **empty values** like it happens when you open the first url at the first time in your browser without having cookies in your browser, It seems like there is a problem with the cookies of this website and it is stopping me to fetch the data from the First URL so in my case, the UrlFetchApp doesn't work or I'm doing it wrong and if there is anyone can tell me how should I do it then this would be a great help.

Mentioned below is the code I'm using to fetch the data.

```
  function ESTIMATED_SALES() {
    var link = "https://fbatoolkit.com/estimate_ajax?category=UGV0IFN1cHBsaWVz&rank=6000";
    const respond = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link).getContentText();
  Logger.log(respond);
}
```

And here is the execution log of my code

```
12:26:58 AM Notice  Execution started
12:26:57 AM Info    {"sales_per_day_30day_avg": "", "tg_flash": null, "sales_per_day_1day_avg": ""}
12:26:59 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

OR if there is any way to get the data directly from the index page by posting payload data into the specific input field of the index page and get the response back?

Comment: Hi! I'm not into Google scripts, but I checked the URL you're using and that seems to return some empty values too:
{
sales_per_day_30day_avg: "",
tg_flash: null,
sales_per_day_1day_avg: ""
}

Did I miss something, or are you maybe using the wrong url / having an issue with the back-end there?

Comment: Hey, @Jonas when I browse the attached URL in my chrome browser it returns the data which is perfectly fine and this is what I want to fetch in app-script but when I try fetching it in App-Script it only returns the incomplete or insufficient amount of data which isn't useful in my case.

Comment: If i enter the url in my browser it returns blank...

Comment: @RemcoE33 ok I just found out why it's returning the blank value on the very first time you access the URL in your browser and this is what happens when I fetch the data in app-script, So I just tried it in incognito and it returns the blank values so I browsed the index page https://fbatoolkit.com/ to load the cookies, and then in the next tab I browsed that URL and now it is working. So this might be the cookies problem of this website.

Comment: If the data is loaded dynamically you need a "headless browser" that does the page rendering on the server side.